# Disable MTOM on SOAP WS response

Tags: soap, jboss, response, mtom

I have a soap web service, developed in java, which returns a file inside a tag of the XML response. The tag is set to type="xsd:base64Binary". The same software is deployed to two different servers, one running a JBoss AS 7.1.1 and one running a JBoss EAP 7.0.0.

Inspecting the response (eg. with Soap UI), the AS returns a Base64 encode of the file, directly inside the tag:

```
<originalDocument>JVBERi0xLj...</originalDocument>
```

The EAP returns a binary file, with a reference inside the tag (MTOM):

```
--uuid:6ec7448a-58a6-4045-9faf-2b8469edf8b5
Content-Type: application/xop+xml; charset=UTF-8; type="text/xml"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-ID: <root.message@cxf.apache.org>
....
<originalDocument>
   <xop:Include xmlns:xop="http://www.w3.org/2004/08/xop/include" href="cid:84d45c72-2b46-4d8c-9a4d-8bcc0c9206b5-13@cxf.apache.org"/>
</originalDocument>
....
--uuid:6ec7448a-58a6-4045-9faf-2b8469edf8b5
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-ID: <84d45c72-2b46-4d8c-9a4d-8bcc0c9206b5-13@cxf.apache.org>
%PDF-1.4
...
```

Is this a configuration of the JBoss? Or maybe an Apache configuration? How can I force the AS to use Base64 encode?

Please note that I'm referring to the **response** of the endpoint, and **not the request** from client.
And please note also that the software is the same. I'd like to have a server configuration, not a software change.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was to remove `xmime:expectedContentTypes="application/octet-stream"` from the XSD node, and to remove the `@MTOM` annotation. This way the output is always base64. I still did not understand why on the old application server the output was base64, even with @MTOM annotation.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution that works for me. Annotation the corresponding fields in my response type with @XmlInlineBinaryData forces the response to be inline:

```
public class MyResponseType {

    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected String systemLink;

    protected Long fileSize;

    @XmlInlineBinaryData
    protected byte[] md5Hash;
```

My response now looks like that:

```
<ns3:MyResponse>
     <systemLink>system://40278824</systemLink>
     <fileSize>3537</fileSize>
     <md5Hash>oY6Mq54Zgo76VYtxHeVH6w==</md5Hash>
....
```